move/copy code from one repo to another repo without losing git history
i have  two git repos repo-a and repo-b. repo-b is completely empty and repo-a has a subdirectory called some-code (i.e repo-a/some-code). some-code/ folder has codes committed by our team member and basically has lot of git commit history. now i need to move code from some-code/ to repo-b . but while moving i don't want to loose commit history and want to reflect same commit message in repo-b as that of some-code/. how do i do this?
